# Unity3D Выделение контура объекта

Tags: unity3d

столкнулся с проблемой: создал скрипты, позволяющие выделять объекты на сцене. Все выделяет хорошо, НО не совсем так, как хотелось бы: мне надо, чтобы когда я выделил 1 объект, а затем 2, выделение с 1 снималось, а на 2 накладывалось. Решить эту проблему не могу уже долгое время, надеюсь на вашу помощь.
P.S. Выделение осуществляю посредством замены материалов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тексты кодов:
[Первый код]

```
   using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform[] original;
    public Transform[] mask;
    public float shift = 0.01f;
    public string respawnTag = "Respawn";


    public static bool isOn;
    private Transform original_tmp;
    private Transform mask_tmp;
    private Vector3 curPos;
    public bool set;
    public SelectObj selectObj;


    void Start()
    {
        isOn = false;
        set = true;
    }

    public void SetMask(string id)
    {
        if (set == true)
        {
            foreach (Transform obj in original)
            {
                string name = obj.name.Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                if (id.ToString() == name)
                {
                    original_tmp = Instantiate(obj);
                    original_tmp.gameObject.SetActive(false);

                }
                set = false;
            }

            foreach (Transform obj in mask)
            {
                string name = obj.name.Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                if (id.ToString() == name)
                {
                    mask_tmp = Instantiate(obj);

                }

            }
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            curPos = hit.point + hit.normal * shift;
        }

        if (mask_tmp)
        {
            mask_tmp.position = curPos;

            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
            {
                mask_tmp.localEulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 45, 0);
            }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
            {
                mask_tmp.localEulerAngles -= new Vector3(0, 45, 0);
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isOn)
            {
                original_tmp.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                original_tmp.position = mask_tmp.position;
                //original_tmp.position = new Vector3(-20,0.5f,-10);
                original_tmp.localEulerAngles = mask_tmp.localEulerAngles;
                original_tmp = null;
                isOn = false;
                Destroy(mask_tmp.gameObject);
                set = true;
            }
            else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            {
                Destroy(original_tmp.gameObject);
                Destroy(mask_tmp.gameObject);
                set = true;
            }

        }
        Transform objectHit = hit.transform;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&&(objectHit!=null)&&(objectHit.tag!="Respawn"))
        {
            GlobalVar.DontSelect = true;

            objectHit.tag = "Selected";
            GlobalVar.StopSelect = false;
            return;
        }


        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            GlobalVar.StopSelect = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[Второй код]

```
  using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SelectObj : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material matSelect;
    public Material matNormal;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if ((gameObject.tag == "Selected"))
        {
                           gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = matSelect;
            gameObject.tag = "Untagged";
        }
        if ((GlobalVar.StopSelect == true))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = matNormal;

        }
        if ((GlobalVar.DontSelect == true) && (gameObject.tag == "Untagged"))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = matNormal;
            GlobalVar.DontSelect = false;
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Код нужно в виде текста приводить.  Что бы решить проблему не забывай заменять материал назад на не выделенных объектах

Comment: То, что, при клике на следующий объект, на предыдущем выделенном необходимо менять материал обратно, я знаю, но как реализовать это - не понимаю. Может вы подскажете, как это сделать можно в моем случае?

Answer (score 0):

Повесте на камеру скрипт в котором декларируете 2 целочисленные переменные(первая равна 0, вторая -1). При появлении объекта, который можно выделить обратитесь к первой переменной на камере и создайте в скрипте объекта переменную, которую вы приравняете к переменной с камеры. При выборе объекта приравниваете вторую переменную с камеры к переменной с объекта. И в Update на объекте проверяете если вторая переменная с камеры не равна переменной с объекта ставим стандартный материал.